# changing a button text after loading/resetting by bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create like / unlike buttons using bootstrap3.

Here is my button

```
<button type="button" id="testBtn" 
class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
data-loading-text=" ... "  onclick="like()" >
4</button>
```

Here is a simplified version of my JavaScript function without AJAX call:

```
    function like(){
    var btn = $('#testBtn');
    btn.button('loading');

    var current = parseInt(btn.text()); 
    current++;

    console.log(current);

    btn.button('reset');
    btn.text(current);
   }
```

Usually this works and button text increments on each click.

However now that I'm using bootstrap, after resetting the button it keeps the old text even though in the `console.log(current);` I see a new incremented one.

I think because I'm using bootstrap button loading/resetting I have to do something else to change button text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'`btn.text()`' is getting `data-loading-text` value, not '`4`'. So I updated my answer which created vote up and down for you in **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/6xnjcqsu/)**

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="testBtn" class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" data-loading-text=" ... ">
    4</button>
<button type="button" id="testBtnDown" class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" data-loading-text=" ... ">
    4</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('#testBtn').click(function () {
    var cnt=4;
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.button('loading');
    setTimeout(function () {
        cnt++;
        btn.button('reset');
        btn.text('  ' + cnt);
    }, 1000);
 });

$('#testBtnDown').click(function () {
    var cnt=4;
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.button('loading');
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (cnt > 0) {
            cnt--;
        }
        btn.button('reset');
        btn.text('  ' + cnt);
    }, 1000);
 });
```

Comment: thanx , adding little timeout after button reset did it , basically i had to put `btn.button('reset');` before `setTimeout`

Comment: even the small time of timeout, like 1 ms, fixes the problem

Comment: anyone found a better solution? not a fan of `setTimeout()` :p

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is related to that function not being on the global context. You can find more details on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371632/why-cant-i-use-onclick-to-execute-a-function-inside-a-jquery-document-ready).

Basically, recommendation is to do the binding on Document Ready and not to use onclick for this.

Hope this helps!