# modal is not defined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

jQuery Cide:

```
function modal(this) {
        alert($(this).data("id"));
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $state['ID']?>" onclick='modal(this)'>Open Modal</button>
```

Bootstrap Modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: modal is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

I already defined modal outside of document ready function but it displaying me modal is not defined error How to resolve this error?

Comment: the function is defined in _document ready_ handler scope, move function `modal` outside

Comment: Or better yet, use an unobtrusive event handler on the button and get rid of the outdated `on*` event attribute

Comment: Better yet, don't use onclick inline, as it is not recommended.  Use $('#id').on("click", function() {//your code}); instead.

Comment: In HTML events you can only use the functions defined in global scope.

So either move your `modal` function to outside `$(document).ready` or assign a click event using JS.

Comment: I updated code still it not working please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working snippet.

```js
function modal(ref) {
 alert($(ref).data("id"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-id="1" onclick='modal(this)'>Open Modal</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this: [Why can't I use onClick to execute a function inside a jQuery $(document).ready function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371632/why-cant-i-use-onclick-to-execute-a-function-inside-a-jquery-document-ready)

1. Add an id to the button: `id="btnModal"`
2. Delete this: `onclick='modal(this)'`
3. Put this (outside your `document.ready`):

   ```
   $('#btnModal' ).click(function() 
    {
       $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
   ```