# How to make an entire row clickable in live search

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli, livesearch

i am working on a live search.After writing a link in a row using ajax it stop responding

it is a code i have made

//let this page name is index.php

```
<div>
      <input type="search" id="searchterm" name="searchterm" placeholder="Search" >   
</div>
<table id="result"></table>
```

//this is the script of index.page

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_data();
    function load_data(query)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"search.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{query:query},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }



$('#searchterm').keyup(function(){
        var search = $(this).val();
        if(search != '')
        {
            load_data(search);
        }
        else
        {
            load_data();            
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

//this page is search.php

```
$output='';
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
 {
    $keyword=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["query"]);
    $query="SELECT uid,name,lastname ,profile_pic,about FROM comnet_user_details WHERE uid!='$uid' AND concat_ws(' ',name, lastname) LIKE UPPER('%$keyword%')";

 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);



if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
 {
while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $nm=$r["name"]." ".$r["lastname"];
        $profilepic=$r["profile_pic"];
        $about=$r["about"];
        $id=$r["uid"];





  $output .=
     '<table class="msgtab" id="fetchresult">

      <tr  class="trow" onclick="location.href="conversation.php?value='.$id.'"">

     <td class="msg-col-1"><img src="images/profilepic/'.$r["profile_pic"].'alt="Avatar" class="circlemsg"></td>

     <td class="msg-col-2">
        <h5 class="msgheading">'.$nm.'</h5>
        <p class="msgcontent">'.$about.'</p>

        </td>
        </tr>;
        }
         echo $output;
}
```

I expect live search result row should be clickable and clicking on a particular result or row it should lead to the desire page, but my live search results link is not working

Comment: It's gonna be a little hard to debug (without the whole picture). What about `modal is not defined`. It's a javascript error in this case.

Comment: looks like you have your jquery modal function defined within the document.ready.. don't do that. Move the function outside, that should solve the Uncaught Reference issue.  Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929185/modal-is-not-defined-error) and [this one also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371632/why-cant-i-use-onclick-to-execute-a-function-inside-a-jquery-document-ready)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is a typo in `<img src="images/profilepic/'.$r["profile_pic"].'alt="Avatar" class="circlemsg">`
  It need to be `<img src="images/profilepic/'.$r["profile_pic"].'" alt="Avatar" class="circlemsg">`
- Also, `profile_pic` does have also the extension (i.e: 'jpg, png') ?

Edit:

Could you replace the piece of code with this one (hope it will work):
- create a `table`
- in the while loop -> create every row `<tr>`
- then close the `table`

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

   $output = '<table class="msgtab" id="fetchresult">'; 

while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $nm=$r["name"]." ".$r["lastname"];
        $profilepic=$r["profile_pic"];
        $about=$r["about"];
        $id=$r["uid"];


    $output .=
    '<a href="conversation.php?value='.$id.'">
    <tr class="trow">
    <td class="msg-col-1"><img src="images/profilepic/'.$r["profile_pic"].'" alt="Avatar" class="circlemsg"></td>
    <td class="msg-col-2">
    <h5 class="msgheading">'.$nm.'</h5>
    <p class="msgcontent">'.$about.'</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </a>';

    }

$output .= '</table>';

echo $output;

}
```

Comment: ok.do you any idea how should i have to write link in  `<tr  class="trow" onclick="location.href="conversation.php?value='.$id.'""> `   that it can start work

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to make to entire row "clickable", correct?
In that case the best would be to wrap the `<tr>` in an `<a>`. i.e `<a href="conversation.php?value=$id"><tr>...</tr></a>`

Comment: Yes, you are understanding correctly. I have tried as you say like this : `<a href="conversation.php?value='.$id.'">
     <tr class="trow">
    <td class="msg-col-1"><img src="images/profilepic/'.$r["profile_pic"].'" alt="Avatar" class="circlemsg"></td>
    <td class="msg-col-2">
    <h5 class="msgheading">'.$nm.'</h5>
    <p class="msgcontent">'.$about.'</p>
  
    </td>
    </tr>
 </a>` . but it still not working

Comment: thanks for your effort. I had copied the code and pasted it. But, no luck. still irresponsible

Comment: Can you provide these info:
- a screenshot of the output result (what it looks on the browser)
- what the link looks in the devtool
- What happen when you click on the row ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok..After working many times on it I have found a solution of it, and which is working for me. It is like that

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

   $output = '<table class="msgtab" id="fetchresult">'; 

while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $nm=$r["name"]." ".$r["lastname"];
        $profilepic=$r["profile_pic"];
        $about=$r["about"];
        $id=$r["uid"];


    $output .=
'<table class="msgtab" id="fetchresult">

      <tr  class="trow" onclick=location.href="conversation.php?value='.$id.'">

     <td class="msg-col-1"><img src="images/profilepic/'.$r["profile_pic"].'" alt="Avatar" class="circlemsg"></td>

     <td class="msg-col-2">
        <h5 class="msgheading">'.$nm.'</h5>
        <p class="msgcontent">'.$about.'</p>

        </td>
        </tr>';

   }


$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;

}
```

After this, my entire row is clickable now.