# ES6 class object undefined in HTML

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to work with ES6 classes and i'm stuck with the following error :

```
VM1534:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: toDo is not defined
    at eval (eval at onclick (index.html), <anonymous>:1:13)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:35)
```

All i do is click on `Add` Button and the above error is shown in my console and nothing happens :( .

My script.js :

```
class ToDoClass {
    constructor(){
        alert('Hello World');
        this.tasks = [
            {task : 'Go To Dentist' , isComplete : false},
            {task : 'Do Gradening' , isComplete : true},
            {task : 'Renew Library Account' , isComplete : false}
        ];
        this.loadTasks();
        this.addEventListeners();
    }
    addTaskClick(){
        let target = docuemt.getElementById('addTask');
        this.addTask(target.value);
        target.value= "";
    }

    addTask(task){
        let newTask = {
            task : task,
            isComplete : false
        };

        let parentDiv = document.getElementById('addTask').parentElement;
        if(task === ''){
            parentDiv.classList.add('has-error');
        }
        else{
            parentDiv.classList.remove('has-error');
            this.tasks.push(newTask);
            this.loadTasks();
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load',()=>{
    var toDo = new ToDoClass();
});
```

My index.html file :

```
<div class="form-group col-md-1">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="toDo.addTaskClick()">Add</button>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated :) .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I use onClick to execute a function inside a jQuery $(document).ready function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371632/why-cant-i-use-onclick-to-execute-a-function-inside-a-jquery-document-ready). This is just a scope problem. It has nothing to do with classes, ES6, or even jQuery’s `$(document).ready`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable is not declared in the global scope. If you just change the place where it gets declared

```
var toDo;

window.addEventListener('load',()=>{
  toDo = new ToDoClass();
});
```

everything will work as expected.

Comment: Even better: avoid using inline JS entirely, and bind the click event listener to the element instead.

Comment: Using `let` is also possible here it doesn't have to be `var`.

Comment: Thank you :D . Working as expected .

Answer (score 1):

you should put your toDo in the global,because you call the function in the html click.it execute in the global scope.if you put the toDo function in the window.onload.it is in a partial scope.

however,a better way is below,avoid using event in the html;

```js
    class ToDoClass {
        constructor(){
            alert('Hello World');
            this.tasks = [
                {task : 'Go To Dentist' , isComplete : false},
                {task : 'Do Gradening' , isComplete : true},
                {task : 'Renew Library Account' , isComplete : false}
            ];
            this.loadTasks();
            this.addEventListeners();
        }
        addTaskClick(){
            let target = docuemt.getElementById('addTask');
            this.addTask(target.value);
            target.value= "";
        }

        addTask(task){
            let newTask = {
                task : task,
                isComplete : false
            };

            let parentDiv = document.getElementById('addTask').parentElement;
            if(task === ''){
                parentDiv.classList.add('has-error');
            }
            else{
                parentDiv.classList.remove('has-error');
                this.tasks.push(newTask);
                this.loadTasks();
            }
        }
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('load',()=>{
       var toDo = new ToDoClass();
       var btnPrimary=document.getElementsByClassName('btn-primary')[0];
btnPrimary.addEventListener('click',toDo.addTaskClick , false);
    });
```

```html
    <div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
      </div>
```