# How to run onclick function inside a template literal used in Algolia Instantsearch

Tags: javascript

While trying to implement Algolia instant search, I am getting `fnAction is not defined` for the below code.

I have posted this question here assuming it's a Javascript problem.

```
const myColor = 'blue';
let fnAction = () => {
      console.log('Executing action');
    };

instantsearch.widgets.hits({
        container: '#hits',
        templates: {
          item(hit) {
            return `
        <h2>
          ${myColor}:
          ${instantsearch.highlight({ attribute: 'fileName', hit })}
        </h2>        
        <button onclick='fnAction()'>Submit</button>
            `;
          },
        },
      }),
```

For `<button onclick='${fnAction}'>Submit</button>` I get `Unexpected end of input`

What am I missing?

Comment: I think this is because parentesis try `<button onclick="fnAction">Submit</button>`

Comment: @cedricCholley I tried without parenthesis too `fnAction`, same error,  its not defined

Comment: problem was related to scope. referred this  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371632/why-cant-i-use-onclick-to-execute-a-function-inside-a-jquery-document-ready/3371655#3371655

Answer (score 0):

Function `fnAction` was not available in the context.
Making the function global fixed the issue for me.

Ref-
[Why can't I use onClick to execute a function inside a jQuery $(document).ready function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371632/why-cant-i-use-onclick-to-execute-a-function-inside-a-jquery-document-ready/3371655#3371655)